# VS Post Build Event, copy one level above solution folder?

Tags: visual-studio, post-build-event

I currently have

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <PostBuildEvent>copy "$(TargetPath)" "$(SolutionDir)Shared.Lib\$(TargetFileName)"</PostBuildEvent>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

I want to do something like this, but one level above `$(SolutionDir)`

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You can use ..\ to move up a directory.

```
 <PropertyGroup>
    <PostBuildEvent>copy "$(TargetPath)" "$(SolutionDir)..\Shared.Lib\$(TargetFileName)"</PostBuildEvent>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

Comment: what if I just want to copy one particular binary, and not every output file?

Comment: Are you saying that line currently copies more than one file? I would expect $(TargetPath) to point to the exe/library you are building for the project.

Comment: This answer did not work for me. [This one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12521225/6655465) does. The problem lies in the `..\` in quote; it should be outside.

Answer (score 13):

Solution:

```
copy "$(TargetPath)" "$(SolutionDir)"..\"Shared.Lib\$(TargetFileName)"
```

If you have `..\` within the quotation marks, it will take it as literal instead of running the DOS command up one level.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That's exactly what was missing!

Comment: thnx a lot. It worked with me as well. but with copy not xcopy

Answer (score 3):

This is not working in VS2010 .. is not resolved but becomes part of the path

Studio is running command something like this copy drive$:\a\b\bin\debug drive$:\a\b..\c

Comment: Make sure the path you choose exists, it didn't work for me until the path actually existed.

Answer (score 1):

In .Net Core edit csproj file:

```
<Target Name="PostBuild" AfterTargets="PostBuildEvent">
  <Exec Command="copy /Y &quot;$(TargetPath)&quot; &quot;$(SolutionDir)&quot;..\&quot;lib\$(TargetFileName)&quot;" />
</Target>
```

`/Y` Suppresses prompting to confirm you want to overwrite an existing destination file.

Answer (score -1):

xcopy "$(TargerDir)*.*" "$(SolutionDir)..\Installer\bin\"

Note: "../" is used for One level up folder structure